# Web page using bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, web

I have a project where I read 2 sensors using an esp32 and also have an web server. I can connect using mobile phone and display the page where I see info about the sensors (using web sockets to update the info on the page very quickly ) and also send some commands back to esp32. Is working fine, just the issue that when I am connected to esp I don t have internet on my phone anymore (which is a normal thing:) ).
My question is if I can achieve same but using bluetooth instead wifi ? Is there any way to have a "web page" using bluetooth ?
Thank you

Comment: why not connect the esp32 to the same WiFi network you connect your phone?

Comment: Of course you can use bluetooth to comunicate with a webpage
here is an example
https://github.com/hewittwill/WebBluetooth-Terminal

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no such facility in Bluetooth to provide such a feature.  That's not to say that technically it can't be done, there just isn't any software (a web browser) that would support it.

Instead you would need to use a Bluetooth-enabled app on the smartphone to communicate with the ESP32 over Bluetooth and display the data / provide control natively.  Such an app would probably have to be written by you since it would be specific to the way you are working, unless you can find a generic app that lets you design an interface for your project and then communicate using a documented protocol that you would then have to implement on the ESP32.

---

An alternative is to just reverse everything. Instead of having your phone connect to the ESP32 then connect to a webserver on it just have the ESp32 connect to your phone when your phone is set to WiFi Hotspot mode. You can still then get your phone to connect to the webserver on the ESP32, and your phone also has mobile internet. If course, if you are wanting internet through a WiFi connection for your phone then you can't do that. However, your ESP32 can then just also connect to your WiFi router so there is nothing to change on your phone. You just browse to the webserver on the ESP32 through your local WiFi network.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental feature called the [Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API). You could host a single file on a Webserver which then interacts via Bluetooth with your ESP. Keep in mind that aside from localhost you have to use https as protocol. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/bluetooth/) is a Tutorial that shows how you can read and write to Bluetooth caracteristics using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Program your ESP32 to connect to your wifi - it then gets its own IP address on your LAN (e.g. 192.168.1.123 ) - then connect to your ESP from your phone (or anything else on your LAN).

Have you tried micropython? Works amazing on esp32 - makes everything super easy